How does order of services matter in Actix-Web?
Given the following code snippet:
mod handlers;
mod utils;

use actix_files;
use actix_web::{middleware::Logger, web, App, HttpServer};
use handlers::upload_handler;
use std::path::Path;
use tokio::fs;

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    env_logger::init_from_env(env_logger::Env::new().default_filter_or("debug"));

    if !Path::new("./upload").exists() {
        fs::create_dir("./upload").await?;
    }

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .service(web::resource("/upload").route(web::post().to(upload_handler::upload_handler)))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/", "./src/static").index_file("index.html"))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}

Why does swapping the lines serving the static file index.html and handling the upload break the code? With the lines in the following order
.service(actix_files::Files::new("/", "./src/static").index_file("index.html"))
.service(web::resource("/upload").route(web::post().to(upload_handler::upload_handler)))

uploading a file (i.e., creating a POST request) will result in a error:
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload 405 (Method Not Allowed)


The documentation for actix-files' Files says:

Implementation Notes
If the mount path is set as the root path /, services registered after this one will be inaccessible. Register more specific handlers and services first.


In general, .service()s are processed in the order added to your App/Scope. In this case actix-files is at the root and vacuously handles all paths, and thus would handle the /upload path as well and not give the resource a chance.

Very easy to overlook, especially for newcomers to Rust. Thank you!

Interestingly while the order of services can matter and the order of middleware (wrap) matters often even more the order of services vs. wrap doesn't (on the same level), i.e. .wrap(foo).service(bar).service(baz) and .service(bar).wrap(foo).service(baz) and similar are the same (you can use nesting with scopes to avoid this). From a wrapping POV this is strange but from a add middleware POV or for composition it makes a lot of sense.
